# Check if a point is on a 3d line?

Tags: 3d, geometry, points, angle

I know how to check if a point is on a 2d line or not, but I'd like to do this in 3D. Any ideas?

```
        // slope from point 1 to point 3
        var p13:Number = (Math.atan2 (end.x - start.x, end.y - start.y)) * toDegrees;

        // slope from point 1 to point 2 -- matches?
        var p12:Number = (Math.atan2 (point.x - start.x, point.y - start.y)) * toDegrees;

        return Math.round(p12) == Math.round(p13);
```

Comment: think it was asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect

Comment: Algorithmically speaking, this should be on [Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/), although the question may have already been answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normalize the vectors. Check if the normals match.

Find the greatest value, divide all of the other values by that value so you get a vector normal.

Any point on a line should have the same vector normal.

Answer (score 3):

A point can never be 'on' a line in real coords. what you need to do is calculate the distance to the [closest point to the line](http://www.softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0102/) and decide if this is close enough for you.

Comment: -1 - very long and complex solution. completely unnecessary. see Xaade's answer.

Comment: here is a nicer formula:  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html    This solution is good because you don't need to worry about special cases, and your "tolerance" can be a distance rather than an angle.

Comment: @Jenko - the problem with comparing normals is that the distance to the line is proportional to the distance along the line.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't at all clear! If you are using the normalized slope of the line, and the slope (point-line start), then if the point is close to the origin then 1% error in the slope is still close to the line, but if you are a 1000km along the line then a 1% diff in slope could be a long way off.

Comment: @Robinicks Just wanted to add that I was looking for "Xaade's" answer but couldn't find it. After a bit of digging I found out what I expected, it is the answer from "Lee Louviere", they changed their name. I thought this information might be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a line is

v(t) = v0 + t*dir

Where `v0` is some point on a line and `dir` is it's direction. Simply check if your point match this linear equation with enough accuracy